# How can I traverse a hierarchy to find circular references?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that maps employees for profit sharing. It allows a given employee to assign a percentage of their take to another employee. This means there isn't necessarily a single entry for a given employee, there could be 0 or more. Alice could give 5% to Bob and 3% to Charlie, so Alice would have two records in the table.

The table has three fields, `FromEmployeeId` of type `int`, `ToEmployeeId` of type `int`, `PctShare` of type `float`.

When a user attempts to add a new mapping record I need to make sure that it won't result in a circular reference.

The problem is I have both multiple hierarchy levels and each employee can have multiple mappings. Initially I thought a recursive CTE may work but I don't think it will work with the multiple mapping issue.

Here's an example:

```
Bob maps to Charlie and Yusuf
    Charlie maps to David and William
    Yusuf has no mappings
        David maps to Alice and Vince
        Vince has no mappings
            Alice maps to Tucker
                Tucker has no mappings
```

or in tabular form:

```
------------------------
| From      |   To     |
------------------------
| Bob       |   Charlie|
| Bob       |   Yusuf  |
| Charlie   |   David  |
| Charlie   |   William|
| David     |   Alice  |
| David     |   Vince  |
| Alice     |   Tucker |
------------------------
```

If a user attempted to add a mapping record from Alice -> Bob, I want to recognize that that results in a circular reference because Bob -> Charlie -> David -> Alice.

Is my only option something like a cursor and looping through each of the result sets?

Comment: This question on DBA may be relevant, as there are some useful solutions to similar problems: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117469/create-hierarchy-of-multiple-levels-where-each-node-has-a-random-number-of-child